# Go version 1.17.6 is too old for this version of Delve (minimum supported version 1.18, suppress this error with --check-go-version=false)

Tags: go, debugging, delve

Hi，when I start to use dlv to debug the go program. It shows the message means my go version is too old. My go version is 1.17.1 and my dlv version is 1.20.1. So I download the go1.19 and set the   path environment. Now my go version is 1.19 and when I use dlv to debug, it also shows

```
Go version 1.17.6 is too old for this version of Delve (minimum supported version 1.18, suppress this error with --check-go-version=false)
```

can somebody help me out!

I have changed the golang to version1.19 but the message shows "Go version 1.17.6 is too old", but I did download the 1.19 golang and set the path environment.

Comment: use `go1.19` instead of `go`. for example `go1.19 run main.go`

Comment: I wonder why would Microsoft make an error message say "suppress this error with --check-go-version=false)", when they actually mean is "Add "dlvFlags": ["--check-go-version=false"]," to launch.json file". Looks like the UX relies on StackOverflow being there for them.

Answer (score 5):

if you use vscode,you can add '"dlvFlags": ["--check-go-version=false"]' in launch.json

launch.json :

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Launch Package",
            "type": "go",
            "request": "launch",
            "mode": "auto",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "dlvFlags": ["--check-go-version=false"] 
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem, and I have solved it by replacing the DLV bound to Goland with a 1.8.0 support Golang 1.16 DLV version.

1. download an older dlv version supporting your golang version, such as: my golang is 1.16 and dlv use this [delve1.8.0](https://github.com/go-delve/delve/releases/tag/v1.8.0)
2. complie dlv:

```
cd <downloadDir>/cmd/dlv 
go build
```

3. edit goland properties: `Help > Edit Custom Properities...`, and add

```
dlv.path=<yourPath>/cmd/dlv/dlv
```

Answer (score -1):

after changing go version (GOROOT) command `go mod tidy` worked for me.